# React-router need a way to detect route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I search a way to detect route change / leave. I try the exemple https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ConfirmingNavigation.md but i can't make it work in my project.

http://pastebin.com/TXW71gmV

I need to get the next route too, so the route argument `onLeave` doesn't provide anything.

I know i can detect the URL with `document.location` in the onLeave function, but i want something more consistant or built in.

Does anybody can help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The route leave hook does indeed get called with the next location, when the transition is triggered by React Router.

If you're actually leaving the page outright, you're not going to see this, because it will just be hitting the "before unload" hook, from which the router can't build the next location, since it's not something the router is managing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! There https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#onleave, the API said that it doesn't had any   "next location" infos. I created an issue yesterday about adding a nextLocation argument to the `onLeave` hook and i've been shut very quickly :S

Comment: That `onLeave` hook is not the same as the route leave hook that is used in the "confirming navigation" pattern.

Comment: I know but the route leave hook doesn't work in my script :S